# pySpark: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unimplemented type: StringType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, apache-spark-sql

While reading inconsistent schema written group of parquet files, we have issue on schema merging.
On switching to manually specifying schema i get following error. Any pointer will be helpful.

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unimplemented type: StringType
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readDoubleBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:389)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:195)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:230)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:137)

```
source_location = "{}/{}/{}/dt={}/{}/*_{}_{}.parquet".format(source_initial,
                                                                       bucket,
                                                                       source_prefix,
                                                                       date,
                                                                       source_file_pattern,
                                                                       date,
                                                                       source_file_pattern)
schema = StructType([
        StructField("Unnamed", StringType(), True),StructField("nanos", LongType(), True),StructField("book", LongType(), True),
        StructField("X_o", LongType(), True),StructField("Y_o", LongType(), True),StructField("Z_o", LongType(), True),
        StructField("Total", DoubleType(), True),StructField("P_v", DoubleType(), True),StructField("R_v", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("S_v", DoubleType(), True),StructField("message_type", StringType(), True),StructField("symbol", StringType(), True),
        StructField("date", StringType(), True),StructField("__index_level_0__", StringType(), True)])

print("Querying data from source location {}".format(source_location))
df_raw = spark.read.format('parquet').load(source_location, schema = schema, inferSchema = False,mergeSchema="true")
df_raw = df_raw.filter(df_raw.nanos.between(open_nano,close_nano))
df_raw = df_raw.withColumn("timeInWindow_nano",(fun.ceil(df_raw.nanos/(window_nano))).cast("int"))
df_core = df_raw.groupBy("date","symbol","timeInWindow_nano").agg(fun.sum("Total").alias("Total"),
                                                     fun.sum("P_v").alias("P_v"),
                                                     fun.sum("R_v").alias("R_v"),
                                                     fun.sum("S_v").alias("S_v"))

df_core = df_core.withColumn("P_v",fun.when(df_core.Total < 0,0).otherwise(df_core.P_v))
df_core = df_core.withColumn("R_v",fun.when(df_core.Total < 0,0).otherwise(df_core.R_v))
df_core = df_core.withColumn("S_v",fun.when(df_core.Total < 0,0).otherwise(df_core.S_v))
df_core = df_core.withColumn("P_pct",df_core.P_v*df_core.Total)
df_core = df_core.withColumn("R_pct",df_core.R_v*df_core.Total)
df_core = df_core.withColumn("S_pct",df_core.S_v*df_core.Total)
```

Comment: What happens, if you do not specify schema manually (but leave `mergeSchema` option as it is)?

Comment: @Mariusz :As there are some file with out any content as case of no events, so auto inferring results in org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed merging schema of file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot read parquet files in one `load` if schemas are not compatible. My advice would be to separate this to two loads and then union dataframes when you have them compatible. See example code:

```
schema1_df = spark.read.parquet('path/to/files/with/string/field.parquet')
schema2_df = spark.read.parquet('path/to/files/with/double/field.parquet')
df = schema2_df.unionAll(schema1.df.withColumn('invalid_col', schema2_df.invalid_col.cast('double')))
```