# External table on parquet files. .count() works, .show() fails

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hql, hiveql

I defined an external table on a group of partitioned parquet files as such:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE foobarbaz (
      src_file string,
      [...]
      temperature string
      )
      PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
      STORED AS PARQUET
      LOCATION '{1}'
```

If I then run

```
df = spark.table(foobarbaz)
print(df.count())
```

I get the correct non-zero result.

If I run

```
df = spark.table(foobarbaz)
df.show()
```

PySpark raises

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o95.showString. [...]  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Why?

[full traceback](https://pastebin.com/hhBR7xj0)

Comment: It seems table schema and parquet schema is not compatible. May be you can read each parquet file, know the schema and troubleshoot. Here is a ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242983/pyspark-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-unimplemented-type-stringtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue specific to my situation that may still be relevant to future readers. I extracted the schema using parquet-tools. One column was listed as `int96` so in the schema definition I naively used `int` type for this column. Closer investigation revealed the column was of type `datetime`. Changing the schema definition accordingly resolved the issue.